# How to light up back of mesh from emission material or light

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine

I currently have a planet with asteroids.
A sphere with an emissive material is in the back.
The problem is that when the asteroids, which I animated, move in front of the sphere with emissive material, it completely blocks out the "light" instead of letting the emission wash over the asteroids.  I also positioned a spot light with the emissive sphere but it didn't really help.
Is there a better way to solve this problem?
I'm using eevee rendering engine.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you need, but you can try turning on bloom (you might need to crank the emission value or up the spotlight brightness), and play with the bloom settings if needed.

Comment: Tried both of those things.  Emission gets blocked out no matter what.  I'm curious if I should just increase the physical size of the emitting mesh.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are looking to happen. Did you want the light to slightly illuminate the backside of the asteroids, or is something else going on?

Comment: Yeah so this is the setup:
SUN/SUNLIGHT ->  ASTEROID   <- CAMERA
The arrows are directional, so the camera is facing the asteroid with the sun behind.
Now the sun, which is an emissive sphere with a sun light facing the asteroid, should be so powerful that it should wash over the asteroid and all the camera should be able to see is the outline of the asteroid.  But instead the asteroid completely blocks out the sun because the sphere acting as the sun is technically smaller in size than the asteroid.  I could just make the sphere bigger – but is there a better way to solve this issue?

Comment: Yeah, I see what you mean, when the emission gets totally blocked, the bloom goes with it. Hang on, i'm trying a couple of things.

Comment: I tried all combinations of irradiance volume, reflection cubemap, fresnel, and a transparent cube with a volume scatter, and all no good. I'll keep looking, i'm sure there must be an answer, unless this is one of the true limitations of eevee. In the meantime, it's probably easier to just make the asteroid smaller.

Comment: Probably.  Thank you for trying!